# What is the best way to read the db or rest api object in angular framework?

Tags: angular

I am experienced java developer and recently working on angular as well, most of the time i use `observable<any>` as a return type of my http api method or db read method but what is the best way to do this to avoid [`object, object] read error` or  `object is undefined`.

I would appreciate your help. thanks

````
 getComments(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(environment.api + '/payments/6');
  }

  addComments(body): Observable<any> {
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post(environment.api + '/payments/account', body);
  } ```
````

Comment: When did you encounter this problem?

Comment: ** when i am reading on html tags, from object of component **

Comment: what is wrong with your methods? everything seems well. is it possible for you that explain a little more?

Comment: `[object, object] read error` or `object is undefined` are due to some bug in your code. Totally unrelated to your question ("what is the best way to do X"). Bugs can creep into the best designs; even to most experienced developers

Comment: ** actually  these are errors are coming as result of  i am using different ways to read values from db or api**

sometimes i have to use valueChanges to get the object value mainly happening with firebase db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular With interpolation, Angular performs the following tasks:

1. Evaluates all expressions in double curly braces.
2. **Converts the expression results to strings**.
3. Links the results to any adjacent literal strings.
4. Assigns the composite to an element or directive property

Your problem is with section two, when you pass an object to interpolation, Angular converts object to string and the result will be `[object Object]`, so you have to pass some primitives or use `json` pipe to interpolate correctly.

Comment: okay but for an observable object of any type how do we do that ?

Comment: you can use `async` pipe `{{ (data | async)?.someProp }}`